# setting background in tableview when empty data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background

My question is how can I implement a background when the tableview is empty like this:

http://pttrns.com/categories/35-empty-data

I tried to setup an UIImageView as backgroundView for the tableView but it appears always mixed with the empty cells.

Thank you in advance fo your help.

Regards,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to turn off the cell separator and set your empty cells to a clear background color.

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a `TableViewFooter` to the `UITableView`, no cell will be drawn. This way, your image should be visible without mixing with any cells.

Alternatively, you can put the image in a special cell and use that cell as `TableViewHeader` that only gets added when you have no data.

Answer (score 0):

Just cover the table view with a new view that says there's no data. Hide it when there is data.

Answer (score 0):

set an UIImageView behind the table... then at viewwillappear.. if there is no rows for the table.. then set

```
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
```

hope it helps... GL HF